# Regarding CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I am working with a site using HTML/CSS and added a part of code to make links highlight when hovered on; being that the main image on the homepage has a link embedded in it, when you hover over the image, under it highlights?

Any ideas? What can I do to have the code only highlight links that are inside of the `<p> ... </p>` areas of my code?

Here's what I am currently using:

```
p a:hover {< p > < a href="IMAGE LINK HERE"> < /a > Biography < /p >

  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: Please, show that *...added a part of code...* of yours

Comment: @Jon, I would post that as an answer

Comment: @NickMitchinson Posted as an answer. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Answer as requested.  Use

```
p a:hover {
    background-color: yellow; /* Color that it will highlight */
    /* Other styles that you want */
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a really bad developer. Just started yesterday. Here's what I am trying to do:

p a:hover {{<p><a href="LINK OF IMAGE HERE">Biography</a></p>

background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }

So, I want it to highlight white whenever someone hovers over this specific link. I probably did it wrong.

Comment: is `Biography` an ID of the link, or a class?  if ID use `#Biography {background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }` if class, use `.Biography { background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }`

Comment: Based on your comment edit, you'd want to change the link to `<a href="link here" id="biography">Biography</a>` and then use `#biography {background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }` Or, to change foreground color use `color: #FFFFFF` instead of `background-color`.  Based on your question edit, you want the link within your HTML, and the CSS separate, not having the HTML within the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

p a:hover {  }

or you can use simple  a:hover {color:red; text-decoration:underline; }    but it will apply to all your links on site